# How to select a Django Plotly dash element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, plotly-dash

I have a Django Plotly dash app where I have an HTML structure like this:

```
html.Div(
    id="search-topics",
    className="search-topics",
    children=dcc.Input(
        id="search-topic-input",
        type="text",
        placeholder="search...",
        debounce=True,
        className="search-topic-input",
    ),
),
```

I want to select the `search-topics` element in JavaScript so that I can manipulate its properties dynamically. However, when I try to select the element using
`document.getElementById("search-topics`, it returns `null`.

Is there a way to select this element in JavaScript and modify its properties?

any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Where have you put the javascript? If you put the javascript inside a client side callback it should work.